# Joining a view using an existing view in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I created a `table view` and joined it to an existing `view`. Is this a good way?
I'm wondering when the rows in the table piles up, will the performance be affected?

What are the other possible problems that I will encounter when I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say whether this way is good or not. It depends on your database design. Views have some advantages, so if you need to use views, then use them. But views may have bad performance, have a look at this article - [MySQL VIEW as performance troublemaker](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/).